# How to send multiple parameters from jquery to controller

Tags: jquery

I am trying to send two parameters value from jquery to controllers, the problem here jquery only send the first parameter.

JQuery :

```
   save: function () {

        var id = $("#in_id").val();
        var name = $("[name='name']").val();

        KeyWord.updateGroup(id,name,
            function (data) {
                alert("data saved succesfully.");
                self.formHandler.setMode("view");
            },
            function (error) {
                jqXhrErr(error);
            },
            function () {
                Metronic.unblockUI();
            });
    }


var KeyWord = function () {

var url_update = "api/usergroup/updategroup";

return {
          updateGroup: function (id,name, done, fail, always) {
        var jqxhr = $.post(url_update, { id: id }, {name:name});
        return jqXhrHandler(jqxhr, done, fail, always);
    }
}
```

}();

so this code `var jqxhr = $.post(url_update, { id: id }, {name:name});` only send the first parameter which is id, if I change it like this `var jqxhr = $.post(url_update, { name: name }, {id: id});` it will send id only. I want to send both name and id to controller. How to do that?

Comment: do it like this.. `{id: id, name: name}` you only get to send one json object per request..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like this.. `{id: id, name: name}` you only allowed to send one `json` object per AJAX request.. you are sending 2 objects.. one `{id: id}` and the other `{name: name}`

```
var jqxhr = $.post(url_update, { id: id , name: name});
```